# How to install required packages in MikTeX including subrequirements?

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update, dependencies

I'm pre-installing required packages in a MikTeX Docker image, so dockerized PDF jobs run faster.

So I have 3 Docker build jobs:

1. Install MikTeX on debian-slim and install a list of common LaTeX packages.
2. Use the previous image and install tool specific LaTeX packages (e.g. for Sphinx)
3. Finally, I build the PDF documents.

When doing so, I use a `Packages.list` file to specify the list of packages.

I noticed that my PDF build job is still installing dependencies, but I listed all (directly) required packages from the preamble and style template in the packages list file.

**Example:**
I listed `wasysym` in the dependencies, but `wasy` is still missing.

It looks like subdependencies are not installed by the MikTeX package manager `mpm`.
When looking at the [mpm documentation](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html), I can't see any "recursive" flag.

I also tried `--require=@file` and `--install=@file`, but there is no difference in the documentation and in the behavior.

**So my question is:**
How to install only direct dependencies and resolve sub-dependencies automatically by the package manager.

Comment: the package manager can't do this. It doesn't know which (sub)packages a package requires, only if you compile miktex can install missing files on-the-fly. You could compile your file(s) with --recorder to get a list of files it requires and build a list of packages from it.

Comment: As far as I understand, commands provided through packages can only be used if `\RequirePackage{...}` was used. So package source can be scanned for this text recursively. It should be a solvable problem. A try and error approach is not a got computer science solution, right?